# Monitor Kafka Connector Processes and the status of Connector using Elastic Fluentd Kibana

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, efk

The current setup of Kafka connector runs in AWS EKS kubernetes . The connector are self managed. How can we monitor the connector status (stopped/paused) and exceptions from EFK( elastic-fluentD-Kibana)?

We expect the EFK to send an mail on exceptions in connector or when it was paused and stopped. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Write a cron job that loops over and parses the `/connectors/{name}/status` endpoints, then write that data into Elasticsearch

Comment: you mean create k8s cron job and write the data to EFluentdKibana